# Python - Cant import two modules from different folder

Tags: python, module

Good evening.

I would like to import two modules from another folder. I haven't really had any problems with this so far, but...

My project structure is as follows:

```
project\data\...
project\src\
        |---- test_folder\
                  |  
                  |---- test.py 
        |---- utilities\
                  |  
                  |---- api.py   
                  |---- config_reader.py          
        |---- main.py
```

I originally wanted to import the modules api.py and config_reader.py into test.py. Here I always got the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config_reader'".

I also tested it in main.py... Same error.

**Main.py code:**

```
from utilities import api
from utilities import config_reader as cr


def test():
    """
    :return:
    """
    api.simple_api_call("url", header="")
    pass


def handle_liquidated_data(path):
    """
    :param path:
    :return:
    """

    keys = cr.get_json_data(path)["coinglass_settings"]
    print(keys)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    handle_liquidated_data("../data/config.json")
```

**Error & output**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\TEST\src\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from utilities import api
  File "D:\TEST\src\utilities\api.py", line 4, in <module>
    import config_reader
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config_reader'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**BUT:**
If I import only one module, then it works and there is no error...

```
#from utilities import api
from utilities import config_reader as cr


def test():
    """
    :return:
    """
    #api.simple_api_call("url", header="")
    pass


def handle_liquidated_data(path):
    """
    :param path:
    :return:
    """

    keys = cr.get_json_data(path)["coinglass_settings"]
    print(keys)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    handle_liquidated_data("../data/config.json")
```

**Output**

```
{'liquidated_value': {'h1TotalVolUsd': 1, 'h4TotalVolUsd': 40, 'h12TotalVolUsd': 60, 'h24TotalVolUsd': 100}}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Please don't judge me, I'm a student, new to Python and learning.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with your api.py file. You see, whilst importing api, your Python interpreter encounters the line "import config_reader" in your api module, and for that, the interpreter looks to your root directory for config_reader. But of course, config_reader is not in your root directory. Two options: Change line 4 in your api.py file to:

```
from utilities import config_reader
```

Alternatively, move your config_reader module to your root directory.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same error occurs here

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; I have edited my answer.